# In twilio, get usage records(pricing) by number?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

Im using twilio c# api. I want to get the usage record of twilio by number. In other words i want to know what is the total usage by a specific number.

I have gone through the api, there are options like "MonthlyResource" or "DailyResource" but they dont provide which number was used to send/receive sms.

Comment: Also i have tried to get his info manually by addiding up the price of individual sms by:
MessageResource.ReadAsync....

But it doesnt match the pricing given in console.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The usage records API is for calculating usage by subaccount not by number.

You can use the [Messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) to list messages by number and total the price up by that. Your comment says you have done that and it doesn't add up to the price from the console. If that is the case, then this is not a programming problem and you should contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide the discrepancies between your API investigation and the console itself. They will be able to help you and reconcile the issues.

If you need specifically use the usage records API, you could create subaccounts per phone number that you use. That way, the API would be of use.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have thought about subaccounts per phone number, but that might not suit my requirement. Also in it we can run into complex scenarios that might create a problem, like:
If a number is assigned to a subaccount, but then that number is assigned to another subaccount. In that case, what subaccount info we will get? Both subaccounts or latest? How will we be able to keep track of previous subaccounts?

I think twilio should have a feature where we can get usage information by number. Other than that the scenarios become complex for users.

Comment: Also lets say i have 100 subaccounts per phone number. Then to get usage info for 50 subaccounts (phone numbers), we will have to make 50 requests?
If thats the case then it would not be efficient at all.

Comment: A phone number can only belong to one subaccount. It sounds like you need to work out with [support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) why there is a discrepancy between you reading the message prices from using the Messages API and your console.

Answer (score 0):

@philnash,

I have figured out the issue. This c# api call: "MessageResource.ReadAsync();" returns the 'datecreated' and all other date values according to the timezone from where the call was made. And at the console usage section, the monthly calculations are made based on datetime values in UTC time zone.

So for the sms records lying at the end of month say 30th, the c# api call might take them to 1st of next month based on timezone, while in UTC they will be on 30th. Over all yearly cost will be the same but if some is calculating monthly cost that will end up different from console.

All the datetime values should be in UTC, thats what written in twilio documentation but thats not the case here.

I think this is a bug in system, and you guys should ask your engineering team to fix it. I have asked this in your support, but dont know if they will work on it or not